# Why [aviation-history]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

There is currently an [aviation-history](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation-history) tag with 20 posts on it, and no history tag or other tag with history in the name. Why? This whole site is about aviation, it seems like all the tags should be assumed to be related to the site. The aviation bit seems redundant. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems like a rather pedantic argument to me. It doesn't cause confusion, and if you type in "history" as a tag, you get auto-complete for [aviation-history](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation-history). You're right that, in a sense, every tag is implicitly "aviation" already, but unlike most of those tags, the phrase "aviation history" sounds normal and natural as opposed to "aviation IFR" or "aviation pilot."

Essentially, my point is that it doesn't matter, but if enough people want it changed, we'll change it.

Comment: I totally get that it's not worth the bother to change and it's not wrong, but I will note that the much more popular tag "safety" would also work as "aviation safety." Then again, it's a much more popular tag and would be more annoying across the site if it were longer.

Comment: @raptortech97 it's not much effort to change. It's just a question of whether people actually want one tag over the other. If they do, we'll change it. If no one cares, then we'll leave it.

Comment: there are other kinds of history which could be discussed, such as 'avionics history' (four course ranges) and 'aerodynamics history' (da Vinci, say).